# find holidays for persons work in some branches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 table of data: some people work in a branch and others work in 2 or more branch.

We define 2 case holiday: type 1 all branch is Closed and type 0 is some branch is Closed (not all).

Now I want to find person how is in holiday if all person-branch is Closed

#### Holiday

```
ID  Date           AllBranch
1   2019/02/01     1
2   2019/02/05     0
3   2019/02/06     0
```

#### BranchHoliday

```
ID  HolidayID       BranchID
1   2               2
2   2               3
3   3               2
```

#### PersonBranch

```
ID     PersonID       BranchID
1      10             2
2      11             2
3      11             3
4      12             2
5      12             4
```

The result I want is :

```
 PersonID      Hdate
    10       2019/02/01
    11       2019/02/01
    12       2019/02/01
    10       2019/02/05
    11       2019/02/05
    10       2019/02/06
```

In date (2019/02/01) AllBranch is 1 so all person is in holiday

In date (2019/02/05) AllBranch is 0 so:

- PersonID-10 work only in BranchId 2 is define in BranchHoliday table so is in holiday
- PersonID-11 work in 2 branch(2,3) and all 2,3 is define closed in BranchHoliday table so is in holiday
- PersonID-12 work in 2 branch(2,4) and BranchId 4 is NOT define closed in BranchHoliday so is NOT in holiday

In date (2019/02/06)    AllBranch is 0 so:

- PersonID-10 work only in BranchId 2 and branch 2 is define in BranchHoliday table so is in holiday
- PersonID-11 work in 2 branch(2,3) and only branch 3 is NOT define closed in BranchHoliday table so is in NOT holiday
- PersonID-12 work in 2 branch(2,4) and branch 3 is NOT define closed in BranchHoliday table so is NOT in holiday

I need sql query and I am using SQL Server 2016

Comment: On your most recent questions it shows that you are not even attempting to solve your SQL problems :) At least on your C# problems you tried solving them first before asking, and you provided some code, that's good. And also your SQL questions, the way you explain your problem is not clear and can't be deciphered. The example data and example result have no focus, can't connect the dots

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Comment: i explained what i need; i try to find who is in result by his branch-id : if all branch of a person define closed in table 2 then he must be in result

Comment: Yes, you explained. The quality of answer you can get is also based on the quality of how well you explain your problem though. The answers on your most recent questions didn't solve your problems quite completely, or even not at all, and even wastes some other people's time, as your problem definitions are really vague. Try break your problem into small parts. And explain how each of those parts produces a result. It's like your questions can be categorized as "big bang integration"

Comment: For you, the problem definition is obvious to you, or might be obvious to you. The way you convey your problem and the details you provided, be they are too much (no focus), or too little, hardly make your problem obvious to others too. This story might help: http://wiki.c2.com/?TeachMeToSmoke

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7c65d075658deff6c395c344b53f4e87

The result of Esteban's answer didn't match your desired result. His query's result is 7 rows, while yours is 6 only. Either his answer is flawed, or your problem definition has flaws. His answer includes **February 6, 2019** for **Person 11**

Comment: Esteban's query invalidates your problem definition's second statement: `In date (2019/02/06) AllBranch is 0 so: ID-11 work in 2 branch(2,3) and only branch 3 is NOT define closed in BranchHoliday table so is in NOT holiday`. His query incorrectly produces an output that allows Person 11 to allowed to have a holiday on February 6

Comment: I also provided other examples of data on my answer on which you can test your problem definition's expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you accepted Esteban's answer, given that your expected result is this. 6 rows only.

```
PersonID      Hdate
    10       2019/02/01
    11       2019/02/01
    12       2019/02/01
    10       2019/02/05
    11       2019/02/05
    10       2019/02/06
```

Yet Esteban's query produces 7 rows. On February 6 holiday, it wrongly includes person #11 to allowed to have a holiday on February 6. It contradicts your problem definition:

```
In date (2019/02/06) AllBranch is 0 so:
* ...

* PersonID-11 work in 2 branch(2,3) and only branch 3 is NOT define closed 
  in BranchHoliday table so is in NOT holiday
```

Presumably, Person's BranchHoliday(s) should be checked(joined) against the Holiday's  table, right? But Esteban's query is not doing that.

Esteban's query produces incorrect output:

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/86728/2

```
| PersonID |       Date |
|----------|------------|
|       10 | 2019-02-01 |
|       11 | 2019-02-01 |
|       12 | 2019-02-01 |
|       10 | 2019-02-05 |
|       11 | 2019-02-05 |
|       10 | 2019-02-06 |
|       11 | 2019-02-06 |
```

And given these different data:

#### Holiday

```
ID  Date           AllBranch
1   2019/02/01     1
2   2019/02/05     0
3   2019/02/06     0
4   2019/04/02     0
```

#### BranchHoliday

```
ID  HolidayID       BranchID
1   2               2
2   2               3
3   3               2
4   4               2
5   4               4
```

Esteban's query produces incorrect output again:

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/10348/1

```
| PersonID |       Date |
|----------|------------|
|       10 | 2019-02-01 |
|       11 | 2019-02-01 |
|       12 | 2019-02-01 |
|       10 | 2019-02-05 |
|       11 | 2019-02-05 |
|       12 | 2019-02-05 |
|       10 | 2019-02-06 |
|       11 | 2019-02-06 |
|       12 | 2019-02-06 |
|       10 | 2019-04-02 |
|       11 | 2019-04-02 |
|       12 | 2019-04-02 |
```

It should produce this:

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7b6be/1

```
| id |       date |
|----|------------|
| 10 | 2019-02-01 |
| 11 | 2019-02-01 |
| 12 | 2019-02-01 |
| 10 | 2019-02-05 |
| 11 | 2019-02-05 |
| 10 | 2019-02-06 |
| 10 | 2019-04-02 |
| 12 | 2019-04-02 |
```

And given these data. Note that only persons on branch #5 are allowed to have a holiday on April 2.

#### Holiday

```
ID  Date           AllBranch
1   2019/02/01     1
2   2019/02/05     0
3   2019/02/06     0
4   2019/04/02     0
```

#### BranchHoliday

```
ID  HolidayID       BranchID
1   2               2
2   2               3
3   3               2
4   4               5
```

Esteban's query produces incorrect output again, as only the persons on branch #5 are allowed to have a holiday on April 2. Yet his query includes persons that should not be allowed to have a holiday on April 2. Persons #10 and #11 are not included on branch #5, they should not be on April 2.

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fd1d3/1

```
| PersonID |       Date |
|----------|------------|
|       10 | 2019-02-01 |
|       11 | 2019-02-01 |
|       12 | 2019-02-01 |
|       10 | 2019-02-05 |
|       11 | 2019-02-05 |
|       10 | 2019-02-06 |
|       11 | 2019-02-06 |
|       10 | 2019-04-02 |
|       11 | 2019-04-02 |
```

It should produce this. No employees are allowed to have a holiday on April 2, even person #10 is not allowed to have a holiday on April 2, as person #10 is on branch #2 only. Only persons on branch #5 are allowed to have a holiday.

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/299f73/1

```
| id |       date |
|----|------------|
| 10 | 2019-02-01 |
| 11 | 2019-02-01 |
| 12 | 2019-02-01 |
| 10 | 2019-02-05 |
| 11 | 2019-02-05 |
| 10 | 2019-02-06 |
```

### This is the correct query (Postgres version):

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6cf97/2

```
select h.date, p.id 
from holiday h 
cross join person p

join personbranch pb 
on p.id = pb.personid

left join branchholiday bh 
on h.id = bh.holidayid and pb.branchid = bh.branchid

group by h.date, p.id
having  
    every(h.allbranch)
    or 
    -- choose only every person whose branch ids are all present in branchholiday 
    -- filtered by holidayid from holiday.id
    every(bh.branchid is not null) 

order by h.date, p.id
```

Output matches your problem definition's expected output:

```
| id |       date |
|----|------------|
| 10 | 2019-02-01 |
| 11 | 2019-02-01 |
| 12 | 2019-02-01 |
| 10 | 2019-02-05 |
| 11 | 2019-02-05 |
| 10 | 2019-02-06 |
```

### SQL Server version:

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/41a54/3

```
select p.id, h.date
from holiday h 
cross join person p

join personbranch pb 
on p.id = pb.personid

left join branchholiday bh 
on h.id = bh.holidayid and pb.branchid = bh.branchid

group by h.date, p.id
having  
    count(case when h.allbranch = 1 then 1 end) = count(*)
    or 
    -- choose only every person whose branch ids are all present in branchholiday 
    -- filtered by holidayid from holiday.id
    count(case when bh.branchid is not null then 1 end) = count(*)

order by h.date, p.id
```

Output matches your problem definition's expected output:

```
| id |       date |
|----|------------|
| 10 | 2019-02-01 |
| 11 | 2019-02-01 |
| 12 | 2019-02-01 |
| 10 | 2019-02-05 |
| 11 | 2019-02-05 |
| 10 | 2019-02-06 |
```

This is another SQL Server's `every` idiom. You can change the `count(condition) = count(*)` to `min` approach:

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/41a54/4

```
having  
    min(case when h.allbranch = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
    or 
    -- choose only every person whose branch ids are all present in branchholiday 
    -- filtered by holidayid from holiday.id
    min(case when bh.branchid is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Output matches your problem definition's expected output:

```
| id |       date |
|----|------------|
| 10 | 2019-02-01 |
| 11 | 2019-02-01 |
| 12 | 2019-02-01 |
| 10 | 2019-02-05 |
| 11 | 2019-02-05 |
| 10 | 2019-02-06 |
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to break it into two parts:

First selecting the persons for the AllBranch holidays, in a second turn selecting the persons for the specific holidays, where all branches they're working in, have a defined holiday:

```
SELECT AllPers.PersonID, H.Date
FROM Holiday H
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT PersonID 
  FROM PersonBranch
) AllPers ON H.AllBranch = 1
UNION 
SELECT Sub.PersonID, H.Date
FROM Holiday H
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT PB.PersonID 
    , SUM(IIF(BH.BranchID IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS AnyBranchOpen
  FROM PersonBranch PB
  LEFT JOIN BranchHoliday BH ON PB.BranchID = BH.BranchID
  GROUP BY PB.PersonID
) Sub ON AnyBranchOpen = 0
WHERE H.AllBranch   = 0
```